# Jquery datepicker addclass() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker addClass method is not adding class in the div with id #ui-datepicker-div .

**Jquery code :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      //this works
     $('.date-picker1').addClass("mtp");
          //This does not work
     $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("myclassdoesntgo");
     $('.date-picker1').datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         showButtonPanel: true,
         dateFormat: 'yy',
         onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
             var month = 1;
             // month= $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
             var year = 1900;
             year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
             $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 25));
             // $("startDate").val = month;
             $("startMonth").val = year;
         }
     });
     $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('display', 'none');

 });
```

Full code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nik_0811/VS2ek/1/)

Comment: what is `ui-datepicker-div`?

Comment: that is id generated by datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it after you call the datepicker method :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.date-picker1').addClass("mtp");

            $('.date-picker1').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy',
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                    var month = 1;
                    // month= $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = 1900;
                    year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 25));
                    // $("startDate").val = month;
                    $("startMonth").val = year;
                }
            });
      $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("myclassdoesntgo");
      $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('display','none');

        });
```

Full working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VS2ek/3/